# sync animation to a sequence in sqlite 

Tags: iphone, sqlite

When app starts, a sequence of colors flashes based on pattern in database server.

When another user starts the app, it must sync with right color on other open apps. From my research, it says to use an sqlite database to sync to the server and get timestamp when first app opens.

It might be slow to download to sqlite database and compute the time to get the current color to start on, so is there any other way to get the current color?Is it possible.

Comment: How much precision do you need for synchronizing multiple devices?

Comment: anytime anyone opens the app. must know where it is in the pattern and start there.

Comment: How accurate should that be? One second? One millisecond?

Comment: it has to be one second.